# Synchronized counter does not count correctly

Tags: java, synchronization, counter

For each creation of the object, I want it to be uniquely accessible by an identifier. I am using an incrementing static value to keep track of how many objects have been created, and every time a new one is constructed, I make its identifier equivalent to count + 1 (and increment the count). The problem I am encountering is that synchronization is not working. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
public static final Hashtable MODULES = new Hashtable();
private static final Object countLock = new Object();
private static int count = 0;
private final String identifier;
private final String name;

public Class(String name) {
    this.identifier = String.valueOf(incrementCount());
    this.name = name;
    MODULES.put(identifier, name);
}

private static int incrementCount() {
     synchronized (countLock) {
        return ++count;
    }
}
```

Now when I test with this (unrealistically, admittedly, but to be sure that it works):

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Class m = new Class("Name");
            }
        }).start();
    }
    System.out.println(Module.MODULES.size());
```

I get output anywhere from the 60's to 100. Obviously I don't want that sort of unreliability. Would a volatile field work here? (I have tried with the same results) I am not sure how to make sure every `class` object has a different identifier. Any solutions are welcome.

*Note: I do not access to java.util.concurrent for implementation specific reasons.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lock is working fine but the problem is something different. You are initializing the each object through a new `Thread`. **While the threads are running in background, the main thread, prints the count at moment.** Put an appropriate delay in between, you will see the proper count.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Counter m = new Counter("Name");
            }
        }).start();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);//put a delay
    System.out.println(MODULES.size());
}
```

Comment: @joelg236: Don't feel bad. We make mistakes and learn from them. It continues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Class m = new Class("Name");
            }
        }).start();
    }

    Thread.sleep(500);

    System.out.println(Module.MODULES.size());
```

Comment: what's the logic behind using sleep. If I need to do this with out any sleep what should I do? for real life system there's a lot of cases where you can't delay. besides you are sleeping the main thread. What if the main thread is the main listener thread of a web server? Are you not going to lost some valuable requests?

Comment: No, you start printing before all thread started. Pause gives all threads a chance to start. You can do it differently, but make sure that all threads have started then print

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the size of hashtable which is not synchronized. 
add a synchronized statement before the statement MODULES.put(identifier, name);

```
synchronized (MODULES) {
        MODULES.put(identifier, name);
    }
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I see as a problem in your code: The statement `Class m = new Class("Name");` is in the `run()` function, and not in the constructor of `Runnable`'s *implementation* in your code.

If I have to write a similar code, I would write it this way:

```
public class ModuleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            {
                Module m = new Module("Name");
            }
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do something
            }
        }).start();
    }
    System.out.println(Module.MODULES.size());
    }
}
```

Look at the placement of statement `Module m = new Module("Name");` above. It is not in `run()` function, as `run()` is called when `start()` is called. That statement is between unnamed braces `{}` that is called during construction of the anonymous implementation of `Runnable` you have in your code.

And to complete the above code, here is the `Module` class:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Module {

    public static final Hashtable MODULES = new Hashtable();
    private static final Object countLock = new Object();
    private static int count = 0;
    private final String identifier;
    private final String name;

    public Module(String name) {
        this.identifier = String.valueOf(incrementCount());
        this.name = name;
        MODULES.put(identifier, name);
    }

    private synchronized static int incrementCount() {
            return ++count;
    }
}
```